# Writing symbols in R package documentation files (.Rd files)

Tags: r

Is there a way to include symbols in these documentation files? In particular, I would need to include a "degree symbol" (°) for indicating coordinates (e.g. 55°32'32") of a dataset I would like to include and document.

When I currently include such symbol, the document file insert a "Â" character (e.g.55Â°32'32").

Maybe I missed something but I found nothing in the "Writing R Extensions" manual regarding this possibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it from Rstudio (Version 0.99.467):

1. create .Rd file

[image: Rd file creation]

2. insert desired character *(see description field)*

[image]

3. save doc
4. select encoding standard as prompted

[image]

5. preview the file

[image]

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Actually, I use UTF-8 on my computer. RStudio didn't prompt me but I changed the encoding with the "File -> Save with encoding..." menu. Then I choose the ISO encoding and it works.

Comment: Creating and editing Rd files is extremely tedious and completely unnecessary - use RStudio instead, which lets the `devtools` and `roxygen2` packages do the heavy lifting. So the actual answer would be to do it in Unicode, as provided [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32090034/4575331).

Answer (score -2):

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html <- It's under the CRAN section.

1. Find the Unicode character: **°**
2. Find the code associated with the Unicode character: **U+00B0**
   http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm
3. Format it as `"\u00b0"`.
4. And I think you're good!

Comment: Thanks, but I think your solution works for the code but not the documentation files that rely on some LaTeX conversion if I well understood. I receive a "unknown macro '\u00b'" warning when using it in Rd file (and it actually write 'u00b' in the documentation).

Comment: He is not wrong at all - this is indeed for R code, but pretty much all R developers use the `roxygen2` package for documentation nowadays, by using `devtools`. It requires you to put the documentation parts in the R files, and the Rd files will be generated automatically. So, this answer provides the solution for best practice nowadays. Many thanks!